# various ways to get session access object in struts2 other than implementing SessionAware interface

Tags: java, session, struts2

guys I'm beginner to Struts2 .i'm trying to use session but i could not create session object by implementing `SessionAware` So is there is any other way to creates session object other than  `SessionAware` thanks in advance
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Map session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
```

you can use the above method to get session object

Comment: `Map session = (Map)ActionContext.getContext().getSession();` need conversion.